# angularjs can't communicate with php using POST

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http, post

I am trying to send and then get data from PHP on my server, but I don't think it sends the data.

My js code:

```
angular
    .module('h2hApp', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function(scope, http) {

        scope.initGames = function() {
            http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'apis.php',
                data: {
                    url: someUrl
                }
            })
                .success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
        };

        scope.initGames();
    }]);
```

and my PHP file:

```
<?php
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

The only thing I get in response is that error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: url in /my/path/apis.php on line 2
```

I made this working using jQuery but with AngularJS it doesn't seem to work. I'm new to Angular and I read some other problems like this. I tried things like adding headers and other things but nothing worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can be forgiven for thinking that your *PHP* script should be expecting data in the `$_POST` variable as encoding your data as a query string has traditionally always been the default mechanism.

Angular however encodes the message body as a *JSON* object by default.  As mentioned you could use the `params` instead however in the long run I'd argue that it's more flexible to conform on the server-side.  For example you can read and decode the message body as follows:

```php
<?php
    $data = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );
    echo $data->url;
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be 'params', not 'data'. See [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#usage)

Comment: Tried that. Still the same :(

Comment: What do you see in your browser's network log when the function "initGames" is being executed?

Comment: @iceless `params` are sent as part of the api url - ***i.e.*** the variable would be in `$_GET['url']` instead of post.

Comment: @Emmissary Yes, using $_GET['url'] works fine with params. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to set the HTTP header, sort of like this:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
```

[More info on using Post from AngularJS to PHP](http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`http.post()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#post) method -

Try this the code -

```
http.post('apis.php', {
                    url: someUrl
                })
                .success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

Comment: The post method is just a helper function.  His approach is not inherently wrong.